# A proof for the Final Value theorem using Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm going over the proof for the Final Value theorem using the Dominated Convergence theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem), I don't understand how from the equation

$$sF\left(s\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{t}{s}\right)e^{-t}dt$$

and the fact that $\left|f\left(\frac{t}{s}\right)e^{-t}\right|$ is dominated by $Me^{-t}$ they get to the limit

$$\lim_{s\searrow0}sF\left(s\right)=\int_0^{\infty}{\alpha}e^{-t}dt=\alpha$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\lap}{\mathscr{L}}$I went through the proof again, and I think that you're right. The variables are intertwined and the proof is not rigorous. Here's the correct statement:

**Final value theorem.** Suppose that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $f$ is continuously differentiable and both $f$ and $f'$ have a Laplace transform
2. $f'$ is absolutely integrable, that is, $\int_0^\infty|f'(\tau)|\dd\tau$
   is finite,
3. $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists and is finite,

Then,

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{t\to \infty}f(t) = \lim_{s\to 0^+}sF(s).
 \end{equation}

*Proof.* We know that the Laplace transform of the derivative is

\begin{equation}
  sF(s) - f(0^+) {}={} \lap\{f'(t)\}(s) {}={} \int_{0^+}^\infty f'(\tau) e^{-s\tau}\dd\tau.
 \end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
  \lim_{s\to 0^+} sF(s) {}={}& f(0^+) + \lim_{s{}\to{}0^+} \int_{0^+}^{\infty}f'(\tau)e^{-s\tau}\dd\tau
  \notag
\end{align}

We want to use the dominated convergence theorem ; Define $\phi_s(\tau) = f'(\tau)e^{-s\tau}$. We have $|\phi_s(\tau)|\leq f'(\tau)$ which is assumed to be absolutely integrable (Assumption 2). Therefore,

\begin{align}
\lim_{s\to 0^+} sF(s) 
 {}={}&f(0^+) +  \int_{0^+}^{\infty} \lim_{s{}\to{}0^+} f'(\tau)e^{-s\tau}\dd\tau
 \notag
 \\
 {}={}&f(0^+) +  \int_{0^+}^{\infty} f'(\tau)\dd\tau
 \notag
 \\
 {}={}& {f(0^+)} +  \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t) - {f(0^+)},
 \\
 {}={}&  \lim_{t\to\infty} f(t).
 \end{align}
This completes the proof. $\Box$

Comment on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) (8 May, 2019): it is stated that with a change of variables, $\xi = st$, (in fact, the same symbol is used for $t$ and $\xi$), the integral becomes

$$
\int_0^\infty \lim_{s\to 0^+}f(\xi/s) e^{-\xi}\dd\xi.
$$

As the OP noted, there is some confusion in that proof; in fact, $\xi$ and $s$ are not independent variables (by definition), so the limit $\lim_{s\to 0^+}f(\xi/s)$ is not equal to $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$.

---

**Update:** Following @LaurentLessard's comment, here is a different proof that requires $f$ to be bounded

**Final value theorem #2.**  Let $f$ be a function in the time domain with Laplace transform $F(s)=(\mathcal{L} f)(s)$. Suppose that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $f$ is bounded,
2. $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists and is finite,

then,
$$
    \lim_{t\to \infty}f(t) = \lim_{s\to 0^+}sF(s).
$$

*Proof.*  We observe that
\begin{align}
    sF(s) = \int_0^{\infty} f\left(\frac{y}{s}\right)e^{-y}\dd{}y.
\end{align}
Define the function $f_s(y) = f\left(\frac{y}{s}\right)e^{-y}$. Since $f$ is assumed to be bounded, there is an $M>0$ such that $|f(t)| \leq M$ for all $t\geq 0$, therefore, $|f_s(y)| \leq Me^{-y}$. As a result, we can apply the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem):
\begin{align}
    \lim_{s\to0^+}sF(s)
    {}={}                     &
    \lim_{s\to0^+}\int_0^{\infty} f\left(\frac{y}{s}\right)e^{-y}\dd{}y
    \notag                      \\
    \overset{\text{dct}}{=}{} &
    \int_0^{\infty} \lim_{s\to0^+}f\left(\frac{y}{s}\right)e^{-y}\dd{}y
    {}={} \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t).
\end{align}
This completes the proof. $\Box$

Comment: How did you make the step $\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{s\to 0^+} f\left(\frac{\xi}{s}\right)e^{-\xi}d\xi = \lim_{s\to 0^+} f\left(\frac{\xi}{s}\right)\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{s\to 0^+}$ if the limit depends on $\xi$?

Comment: @SIMEL Thank you for accepting my answer. Let me rewrite it in a more clear way. I'll also add the statement of FVT for completeness.

Comment: I think Assumption 3 is stronger than it needs to be. It appears the only place Assumption 3 is used in the proof is in the first step; to ensure that the formula for the Laplace transform of the derivative holds true (because proving it involves integration by parts, and we need $f(t) e^{-st} \to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ when $s>0$). But this will hold under weaker conditions, such as $f$ being bounded, or even growing polynomially. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LaurentLessard are you referring to assumptions 1 and 2? Indeed, they are stronger and FVT can be proven using the assumptions that $f$ is bounded and the limit $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists and is finite. The boundedness assumption can be relaxed further as you said. The proof uses the dominated convergence theorem. I will add another answer in the weekend with the proof.

Comment: @Pantelis I was talking about assumption 3. I have seen other versions of FVT where very few assumptions are needed --- see e.g. the "elementary proof" in the FVT wiki article, which only assumes $f$ is measurable and bounded, and the limit $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$ exists and is finite; no need for differentiability, existence of Laplace, or assumption 2 about $f'\in L_1$.

I was actually hoping for a version of FVT where assumption 3 is not needed; where you can actually _prove_ that this limit must exist and be equal to $\lim_{s\to 0^+} s F(s)$. Kinda like a converse FVT, I suppose.

Comment: @LaurentLessard I updated the proof and assumed $f$ is bounded. There is such a version of the theorem - a generalised version - where it is shown that $$\lim_{s\to 0^+}sF(s) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \tfrac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau.$$ This can be applied to cases where $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ does not exist, such as $f(t) = \sin t$.