# Apply final Value theorem for functions that don't converge

Tags: functional-analysis

This is in continuation of the question [A proof for the Final Value theorem using Dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218574/a-proof-for-the-final-value-theorem-using-dominated-convergence-theorem/)

I need to show that for a continuous and bounded function such that:

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf\left(t\right)dt = d$$ exists and final (take note that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f\left(t\right)$ doesn't neceserely exist) then 
$$\lim_{s\to0^+}sF\left(s\right) = d$$

Where $F\left(s\right)$ is the Laplace transform of $f\left(t\right)$. I now understand from the previous question how to show that for a function that converges, but how do I show it for a function that doesn't converge but for which the limit above exist?

Comment: Where does $g(t)$ come into the picture?